# Redownloading games

Tags: ps4

I wanted to free up some space on my hardrive, so I deleted some games.

If I want to play them again, will it take as much time to download now as it did when I first purchased the game?

And will all my progress go away?

Answer (score 5):

The download times is going to be about the same since all the game data has been deleted.

Game saves are saved separately and are not deleted when you delete the game. So the game should find these when you download it again.

You can check what saves are available by going to 'Settings > Application Saved Data Management > Saved Data in System Storage'.

You can also check which games are installed and how much space they are using in 'Settings > Storage > Applications'

Answer (score 0):

It will take just as long as it first had, but you should still have all your progress.